# Make a specific column in the new row of XamDataGrid non editable

Tags: wpf, mvvm, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I am trying to achieve as the question suggests, set one column to the new row in the XamDataGrid as non editable,

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
    <igDP:FieldLayout>
        <igDP:Field Name="LOAD_ID" Visibility="Visible">
            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                <igDP:FieldSettings AllowGroupBy="True"
                                    AllowEdit="False"
                                    AllowRecordFiltering="True"
                                    FilterOperatorDefaultValue="Contains" />
            </igDP:Field.Settings>
        </igDP:Field>
        <igDP:Field Name="DESCRIPTION" Visibility="Visible">
            <igDP:Field.Settings>
                <igDP:FieldSettings AllowGroupBy="True"
                                    AllowEdit="True"
                                    AllowRecordFiltering="True"
                                    FilterOperatorDefaultValue="Contains" />
            </igDP:Field.Settings>
        </igDP:Field>
    </igDP:FieldLayout>
</igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
```

I have already set the allow edit to false in case of Load_id but somehow this effects only the already loaded records in the grid, not so much the record to be added.

```
<igDP:FieldLayoutSettings
                AllowAddNew="True"
                AddNewRecordLocation="OnBottomFixed" 
                AutoFitMode="Always"
                AutoGenerateFields="False" HighlightAlternateRecords="True" HeaderPrefixAreaDisplayMode="FieldChooserButton" 
                />
```

It may be a simple property in XamDataGrid controls, but somehow missed by me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
  <ig:UnboundField Label="Filter"  BindingPath="AggregateFilter" BindingMode="TwoWay" >
                            <ig:UnboundField.Settings>
                                <ig:FieldSettings EditorType="{x:Type Editors:XamTextEditor}">
                                <ig:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Editors:XamTextEditor}">
                                            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.isCusipMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ig:XamDataGrid}}}"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ig:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                            </ig:FieldSettings>
                            </ig:UnboundField.Settings>
                        </ig:UnboundField>
```

Comment: Figured out any setter property works in the style, I just had to change the color of the column and after applying that the column itself became non editable since I had the allow edit as false..
thanks for your time..